# How to manually convert a series of quotes to invoices (orders)

Tags: orders, database, invoice, quote

For about 24 hours yesterday we were experiencing an issue where Magento could not create new invoices. It has since been resolved but I now have a series of orders (22) that are trapped in the sales_flat_quote tables. The customers' credit cards have been charged however their orders are not showing up in our order grid. I need to get these quotes out of limbo and into the order phase.

I initially tried switching sales_flat_quote.is_active to 0 but it requires more than that for Magento to move data to the sales_flat_order tables. Any idea how to proceed?

UPDATE: Currently investigating a programmatic approach that might trigger Magento quotes to be processed: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Comment: We are in a similar situation, do you still have the code you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got some quotes in sales_flate_quote table, you could easily convert them to an order. It's only working if all required information like payment method, shipping & billing addresses are correctly set.

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1);

// convert quote to order
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();

$order = $service->getOrder();
```

Comment: I do have all the information. So basically package it in this correct? <?php require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento umask(0); Mage::app();

Comment: No. That will not trigger events.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I'm not familiar with how to implement this. Does this code need to be packaged into a controller and executed?