# How to properly implement this snippet of code

Tags: php, event-observer, controllers

I'm in the process of manually turning a few quotes into orders. Someone was kind enough to provide me the code that should do it from another question ([How to manually convert a series of quotes to invoices (orders)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46975/how-to-manually-convert-a-series-of-quotes-to-invoices-orders)). I'm not familiar with how to implement the following snippet:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1);

// convert quote to order
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();

$order = $service->getOrder();
```

Should this be inserted into a new controller and executed by namespace URL? I was originally going to preface this code with:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

However I'm told it will not trigger events.

With that said, what would be the best way to implement this? Thank you.

Secondary Question: What does the "load(1)" mean in the first line of code? Is that a reference to the quote ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(1);
```

1. Resolve the `sales/quote` argument to a class (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` by default)
2. Have the model invoke its resource model (`Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote` by default) to transact with storage
3. Read the `sales/quote` entity data with primary key of `1`
4. If the record exists, decorate the `sales/quote` instance with data

*You should perhaps work through Alan Storm's articles in the Magento KB - [particularly the ORM chapter](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics).*

If you want to run it via Web request I would lock the script down. What you are doing is a utility activity and probably doesn't require configuring a route (especially if it's a one-off or infrequent process). Whereas any PHP script in the webroot can be accessed directly, you can just do this as you are intending to - with what I call a [workbench script](https://gist.github.com/benmarks/4532434) (link contains notes):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require 'app/Mage.php';
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); //uncomment if stuff's broken
umask(0);

Mage::app();
```

Now, if you need emails to go out, you want to make sure that theme and locale settings are applied. Do this with [app emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055742/833795):

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
/*
 * Any code thrown here will be executed as we are currently running that store
 * with applied locale, design and similar
 */
//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Then you just need to load the proper areas:

```
 Mage::app()
     ->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS)
     ->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
```

(*I might be getting superfluous with the emulation (getting rusty), but it shouldn't hurt and someone will correct me if I'm wrong.*)

Comment: Thank you, that's very informative! This is a one-off solution so the workbench script method would suffice. However I'm getting a long error when I attempt either method that seems to be related to process: 'Quote totals must be collected before this operation.' https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhyb8hd4v59q5dq/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2013.58.10.png?dl=0