# Recurring Payment Profile Error

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, orders, recurring

I'm running a store which is not configured to handle recurring payment profiles. This morning I receive (for the first time every) the following payment transaction failed reminder:

`Quote totals must be collected before this operation`

The only instance I could find where this error is generated is within `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` under the following method:

```
public function prepareRecurringPaymentProfiles()
{
    if (!$this->getTotalsCollectedFlag()) {
        // Whoops! Make sure nominal totals must be calculated here.
        throw new Exception('Quote totals must be collected before this operation.');
    }

    $result = array();
    foreach ($this->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        if (is_object($product) && ($product->isRecurring())
            && $profile = Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile')->importProduct($product)
        ) {
            $profile->importQuote($this);
            $profile->importQuoteItem($item);
            $result[] = $profile;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I'm not familiar with recurring payment profiles whatsoever, and am struggling to understand how this error occurred? Would appreciate any insight.

**Edit:** I have read the following resources:

[Quote totals must be collected before this operation…. Blah, Blah, Blah… What a PITA You are Magento!](https://journalxtra.com/magento/quote-totals-must-be-collected-before-this-operation-blah-blah-blah-what-a-pita-you-are-magento/)

- This approach did not work for me

[How to properly implement this snippet of code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48074/how-to-properly-implement-this-snippet-of-code)

- We have been using our theme & not made any recent design changes for over 2 years which leads me to believe this is not the problem. We have never seen this error pop up before.

Comment: Can i see the code that creates the order I had this issue two weeks ago

Comment: @DavidManners - this was quite literally just the standard one page checkout process. P.S. We do not support a payment gateway either.

Comment: oh ok then it is different. I had it on charging the profile and not on setting up the profile. Solved it by collecting totals during the charge process on the payment model's recurring profile methods